# How do I Mock a HTTPBuilder in Groovy?

Tags: testing, mockito, httpbuilder

My REST API will use `HTTPBuilder` to request a response from some URL.

The response to the request will contain a body with XML or Json content.

I already have this response, I want to mock the `HTTPBuilder` as: *if {this URL} then return {that content}*.

Does anyone have an example a mocked `HTTPBuilder` or know how to implement it ?

Comment: I would recommend using something to mock the server (http://www.mock-server.com/) rather than mocking the builder itself.